# ZF: how to check GET request?

Tags: php, zend-framework, get, request

I have a form. There are two selectboxes which are cannot be 0: field1, field2.
If I set POST method then it works fine. If GET - wrong.

Here my controllers' part:

```
$this->view->searchForm = new Default_Form_Parameters();
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
if ($this->view->searchForm->isValid($data)) {

}
```

If I have following request then isValid returns false. That's ok.

```
http://site.ru/?field1=0&field2=0
```

If I have another request like

```
http://site.ru/?crash
```

then  isValid returns true. That is wrong.

Any ideas whats the problem?

PS here one of fields with validator:

```
$required = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
$required->setType ($required->getType() | Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::INTEGER | Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::ZERO);

$input = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('cat');
$input->setLabel('theme')
      ->addMultiOptions(array('0' => ' ----------- ') + $categories)
      ->addValidators (array ($required));
```

Comment: Can you show form code - validators assigned to that fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a `Zend_Validate_NotEmpty` validator isn't enough. It only applies if a value has been set to this field. If an empty value like `''` would be set it wouldn't validate. However, by defaults it's set to `Null` I think and that means no value has been set. You have to tell it that it that is  `'presence' => 'required'`, or use `setRequired()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $this->_request->getParam('getkey');    
if($data)
{
    //do something
}
else{
    throw new Zend_Exception("No GET value");
}
```

Comment: `field1` and `field2` are probably allowed to be empty.

Comment: @Htbaa - there are not allowes to be empty. The code fragment added above.

Comment: You have to add a `'presence' => 'required'` I think.

Comment: @Htbaa. You were right. I added ->setRequired() and it works fine now! Could you set this message as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use to work with forms...

```
public function createAction()
    {
    $form = new Application_Form_PageCreate();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
             //do what you need
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
    }
```

as you can see I use "getPost()" and not "getParams()" but that's in cause of my FORM method

Comment: I prefer to use url written in sitename.com/controller/action/param1/key1/param2/key2/param3/key3 that let me correctly get them as Params() instead of GET notation of it ?param1=key1&param2=key2

Comment: thanks. I know the post works fine. Get method had problem. I solved it a few minutes ago)