# ZF: GET parameters duplication

Tags: zend-framework, forms, get, zend-form

As an addition to [ZF: how to check GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401600/zf-how-to-check-get-request).

I have two input fields and one checkbox. The form is standart.

```
public function init()
{
    $this->setMethod('GET');

    $new = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('new');
    $new->setLabel('New')
        ->setOrder(3);

    $app = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('app');
    $app->setLabel('System')
          ->setOrder(2)
          ->setRequired()
          ->addMultiOptions(array('0' => ' ----------- ') + $applications);

    $cat = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('cat');
    $cat->setLabel('Theme')
          ->setOrder(1)
          ->setRequired()
          ->addMultiOptions(array('0' => ' ----------- ') + $categories);

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setLabel('Search')
          ->setOrder(4);

    $this->addElements(array(
        $cat, $app, $new, $submit
    ));
}
```

1) I do the submit where new is 0:  http://site.com/?cat=0&app=0&new=0

2) I do the submit where new is 1:  http://site.com/?cat=0&app=0&new=0&new=1

Why the new field has duplication then? I would be good if new=0 is absent if new=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is because Zend_From creates a hidden input field next to your checkbox. It does it because when checkbox is not checked, by definition, no value associated with the checkbox is being sent to the server. So Zend_Form creates the hidden field to have something sent in case a checkbox is unchecked. However, the drawback is that when the checkbox is checked, two values are sent, i.e. a hidden one and the actual value of checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to hide new=0?

Comment: @Anthony. I believe Zend_Form always creates this hidden field for checkbox (except when checkbox is disabled). So, the only thing that comes to my mind would be to try to manipulate the form using JS. You could remove hidden field when checkbox is checked, and add it when it is not. Or just use POST to submit your form.

Comment: unfortunately I need only GET request. May be to make own zend_view_form component where GET url is formed? But I dont know exactly where it is formed:(

Comment: @Anthony. The html for Zend checkbox is generated in [Zend_View_Helper_FormCheckbox](https://github.com/mridgway/Zend-Framework-1.x-Mirror/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/FormCheckbox.php#L60). You can see at line 92 that the the hidden field is also generated. So you could make your own custom helper with an option to remove this hidden field or just without this line. Having the new helper you would also need to tell your instance of Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox to use the new helper instead of the orginal one.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you care? It should work just fine?

If you DO care for any reason, you can create My_View_Helper_MyCheckbox that won't create the hidden element and assign it (easily, without juggling wth zend_view_helper prefixes) like this:

```
$decorators = $form->new->getDecorators();
//see which key is ViewHelper and assing it to $key variable
$decorators[$key] = new My_View_Helper_MyCheckbox();
$form->new->setDecorators($decorators);
```

But note that can bring some complications - like the checkbox may not validate for unchecked state any many other flaws you can't even think of right now. So consider wisely ;)

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Seems Marcin means the same:) Anyway I created own helper and it works perfectly!:)

Comment: Yes, he does. I just wanted to add the code how to change the view helpers easily. And it would be too long for comment. The other option (the suggested in manual) is kinda longish and to much overkill for this task I guess ;)